# date and days of week problem

Tags: contest-math

> A competition in 2017 starts on Thursday, Mar 2nd. If the committee decides to set the start date for the next competition to be on the first Thursday of March in 2018, what is this date?

A year ($365$ days) later it would be March 2nd 2018. However, since $365$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $7$ (number of days in a week), Mar 2nd 2018 is Friday and so the first Thursday of March in 2018 would be on Mar 1.

Am I correct in thinking so, and are there other ways to approach the problem?

Comment: That's absolutely correct, and is the way I would approach the problem (i.e. using $365\equiv 1\pmod 7$). In fact, checking the calendar, we indeed see that March 1st, 2018 is a Thursday.

Comment: I agree with Dave,on a side note I'm kinda curious to what competition is this from?

Comment: The only other wrinkle to look out for is the case in which the interval between the two start dates includes February 29, in which case "the same date next year" is _two_ days later in the week; but that does not happen between March 2, 2017 and the first Thursday in March, 2018.

Comment: so, not a complete verification, but the first Thursday will be either the first, second,..., or seventh of the month